# Importing Accounts Common returns undefined

Tags: meteor, accounts

Running this code : `import { AccountsCommon } from 'meteor/accounts-base'` returns undefined.I added the accounts-base package so I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is

```
import AccountsCommon from "meteor/accounts-base";

AccountsCommon.Accounts.onLogin(function() {
});
```

I am using Meteor 1.4.1.x.

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Accounts should work in place of AccountsCommon

`import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'`

Comment: I already imported `{ Accounts }` and same the AccountsCommon is undefined.